# Django urls to render form in Jquery enviroment

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I've page with [step wizard](http://mstratman.github.com/jQuery-Smart-Wizard/) where all steps are on a single html template which can be navigated through page id like"id='step-1'","id='step-2'".

I've created form on step3 and try to render it here on this step. While in my browser address bar url is the same on all steps (they all are on single template).

I added string "location.hash= "step No"" to jquery code and now when navigating steps address bar changes so I have `steps/#2`, `steps/#3` respectively.

But when in my urls.py I wrote "url(r'^steps/#3', my_view")it doesn't work.

#### What might be wrong and will this work as I want. Hope I've explained all clearly.

steps.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% csrf_token %}


  {% block step1 %}

<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td> 
    <div id="wizard" class="swMain">
            <ul class="anchor">
              <li><a href="#step-1" class="selected" isdone="1" rel="1">
                    <label class="stepNumber"></label>
                    <span class="stepDesc">
                       Step 1<br>
                       <small>Generate</small>
                    </span>
                      </a></li>
              <li><a href="#step-2" class="disabled" isdone="0" rel="2">
                    <label class="stepNumber"></label>
                    <span class="stepDesc">
                       Step 2<br>
                       <small>test</small>
                    </span>
                </a></li>
              <li><a href="#step-3" class="disabled" isdone="0" rel="3">
                    <label class="stepNumber"></label>
                    <span class="stepDesc">
                       Step 3<br>
                       <small>generate server keys</small>
                    </span>                   
                 </a></li>
              <li><a href="#step-4" class="disabled" isdone="0" rel="4">
                    <label class="stepNumber"></label>
                    <span class="stepDesc">
                       Step 4<br>
                       <small>create</small>
                    </span>                   
                </a></li>
            </ul>


      <div style="height: 312px;" class="stepContainer"><div style="display:    none;" class="content" 
             id="step-1">  
                <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 1 Generate and Test Key </h2>
                <ul type="disk">

                </ul>
                <p><h3>Welcome!</h3>
                </p>
                <p>
               This wizard will help you 
                </p>
                <p>

                </p>                
                <div>

            </div>
            <div style="display: block;" class="content" id="step-2">
                <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 2 Content</h2> 

            </div>
            <div style="display: none;" class="content" id="step-3">
                <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 3 Content</h2> 



                <p>
                 {{ form.as_p }}
                </p>                                
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;" class="content" id="step-4">
                <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 4 Content</h2> 

                <div>
                    <form>
                    <h4>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h4>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>



{% endblock %}
```

view.py:

```
 def StepsPageView(request, step_id):
        stepNumber = step_id
        step2 = 'step2.html'
        step3 = 'step3.html'
        form = VarsDataForm()
        if stepNumber==2:
           return render_to_response(step2,{}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        elif stepNumber==3:
           return render_to_response(step3,{"form":form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Could you put related code here~ A little difficult to check without code but just description

Comment: The URL mapper does not handle hashes in URLs for a simple reason: the browser does not transmit them. You can use the path only. No hashes, no query string.

Comment: Is there any way to add real path in my case to call view?

Comment: I made step3.html with the same content as steps.html and added {{ form.as_p }} then following you made view( see above) but it still doesn't work

Comment: i think you are trying to render different contents on a single page with jquery, but did you remember to include the necessary js files?